# Can I play as Commander Video or the other unlocks in story mode?

Tags: retro-city-rampage

I enjoy the cameos from different video games and am wondering if these unlockable characters are available to be used in story mode, just like in Super Meat Boy.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the PC/Steam version of the game

```
U,U,U,U,L,R, PgDn, Ctrl, PgDn, Ctrl, PgDn
```

will unlock all characters for use in "Free" Mode, not story mode that I'm aware of.